# CKEditor get table dialog class init Value in Set Up function of another element added on dialogDefinition

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, ckeditor

PLEASE READ QUESTION BEFORE READING CODE!!!

I've added a checkbox element on Dialog definition of the table dialog (it works). Now I want the checkbox to be checked by default when the table being edited has a certain class (which is usually visible on the advanced tab). According to the documentation, I should be able to do something like this in my setup function. I've tried many things and you  could hopefully help me. This is my code.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( evt )
{
    var dialog = evt.data;
    if(dialog.name == 'table' || dialog.name=='tableProperties')
    {
        // Get dialog definition.
        var def = evt.data.definition;
        var infoTab = def.getContents( 'info' );

        infoTab.add(
        {
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 'myCheckBox',
            label: 'Table Has Property',
            setup: function()
            {
                //Class to look for if I successfully get the input's value
                var classValueToLookFor = 'has-property';

                // The current CKEditor Dialog Instance
                var thisDialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();

                // The Element whose value I want to get
                var classElement = theDialog.getContentElement('advanced','advCSSClasses');

                // Trying to Get Value of this class Element According to documentation
                var containedClasses = theDialog.getValueOf('advanced','advCSSClasses');

                // Trying to debug the value above
                 console.log(containedClasses);  // This shows nothing

                // Trying to debug InitValue which shows something according to prototype 
                 console.log(classElement.getInitValue()); //This also shows nothing

                //Checking if Element has the class I'm looking for to mark the checkbox
                if(containedClasses.indexOf(classValueToLookFor) != -1)
                {
                    //Check current checkbox since value has been found                    
                    this.setValue('checked');
                }
            }
            onClick: function()   // You can ignore this function, just put it in case you were wondering how I'm putting the has-property, might help someone else (works well) ;)
            {
                 var checked =  this.getValue();
                 var classValueToSet = 'has-property';
                 var thisDialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
                 var containedClasses = theDialog.getValueOf('advanced','advCSSClasses');
                 if(checked)
                 {
                      if(containedClasses.indexOf(classValueToSet) != -1)
                      {
                        //console.log('already contains class: '+classValueToSet);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        containedClasses += containedClasses+" "+classValueToSet;
                      }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      if(containedClasses.indexOf(classValueToSet) != -1)
                      {
                           containedClasses = containedClasses.replace(classValueToSet,'');
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        //console.log('already removed class: '+classValueToSet);
                      }
                 }
                 thisDialog.setValueOf('advanced','advCSSClasses',containedClasses);
            }
        }
}
```

Here are some debug statements that can be helpful to add into the setup function and understand what is going on, you shouldn't need to go through all I've went through ;)

```
console.log('in setup function');
console.log(classElement);
console.log(classElement._);
console.log(classElement.getInitValue());
console.log(classElement.getInputElement());
var inputElement = classElement.getInputElement();
var inputElementId = inputElement.getId();
console.log($('#'+inputElementId+'.cke_dialog_ui_input_text'));    
console.log(classElement.getInputElement().value);
```

It would be nice to test your answer before suggesting. Many of the things I've tried should work in theory, but are practically not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so finally after a few days of trial and error, this is what finally worked for me. Maybe it could be helpful to someone. I'm sure there should be a much cleaner way to do this. All the best to everyone.

```
setup: function()
{
   //This current checkbox
   var checkbox = this;

   //the class I want to find on my table
   var var classValueToLookFor = 'has-property';

   //Current Dialog instance
   var thisDialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();

  //This code below gets a <td> element in the table
   var startElement = thisDialog.getParentEditor().getSelection().getStartElement();

  // This gets me the parent of the <td> element which is my current table instance
   var parentTable = $(startElement.$.offsetParent);

  //Finally check if the table has the property I'm looking for.
   if(parentTable.hasClass(classValueToLookFor))
   {
       //Mark the checkbox
       checkbox.setValue('checked');
   }

}
```